# Counting number non-reachable integer solutions of a Linear Diophantine Equation.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

Suppose we have a Linear Diophantine Equation $$a_k x_1 + a_{k+1} x_2 + ...+a_{k+n-1}x_n  $$
where, $a_k>0 , n>1$ and $x_i>0$

And it is given that $$gcd(a_k, a_{k+1}...a_{k+n-1}) = 1$$

the question i am trying to answer is the number of non-negative unreachable integer solutions for this equation under given conditions.

*for example*, $$ n=2, a_k = 3, a_{k+1}=4$$
*here*, $gcd(3, 4)=1$

*the equation becomes*
$$3x_1 + 4x_2$$
*possible unreachable integer values*, 
$$1, 2 , 5$$
Is there some kind of formula to answer it for all $n>1$?

Note that there are always finite number of unreachable non-negative integers for $n>1$.

Comment: Only non-negative values, Edited now.

Comment: @UtkarshPandey Your comment & update basically indicates non-negative values, but your statement now says "$x_i \gt 0$". As this problem is related to the Frobenius number (e.g., as described at [Coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem), and that this is a NP-hard problem, I doubt there's any closed-form formula for your case. What is the source of this problem? Based on that, is there any reason to believe there's a known formula for this?